# Accesing a UIView's member variable from another UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have Three different views on iphone. I switch between different views successfully, but I want to access the 1st view's variable in second view's ViewDidLoad method but I can't get it so plz help me on that.

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to the first view on the second one. So, when you instantiate the second one, implement a message that would receive the first view and store a reference to it.

Let me point that it's better to use **ViewController** pattern to orchestrate data and behavior flowing from one view to another.

Comment: can you provide some code? I know how to accomplish what you are trying but I don't know if it's the same path you are taking.

Comment: OK. Going to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Having two subclasses of UIView declared like so:

```
@interface ViewOne : UIView {
    NSString *someVar;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *someVar;

@end

@interface ViewTwo : UIView {
    NSString *referenceToSomeVar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *referenceToSomeVar;

@end
```

You could do the following the reference the "someVar" variable from the first view

```
ViewOne *view1 = [[ViewOne alloc] init];
view1.someVar = @"This is the original variable";

ViewOne *view2 = [[ViewOne alloc] init];
view2.referenceToSomeVar = view1.someVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add something to the code posted above. Imagine that you want to use, the variable from ViewOne an assign it to a second variable in ViewTwo.

```
@interface ViewOne : UIView {
BOO someVar;
}

@property (readwrite) someVar;

@end

@interface ViewTwo : UIView {
BOO referenceToSomeVar;
}

@property (readwrite) BOO referenceToSomeVar;

@end
```

So you have to put in ViewOne .m

```
 ViewOne *view1 = [[ViewOne alloc] init];
 view1.someVar = TRUE;
```

In the SecondView .m

```
 referenceToSomeVar = view1.someVar;
```